# Having text on top of an image in another div

Tags: css

So what I am trying to achieve is have the text in the left side sit on top of the image in the right side

```
<div class="body-content">
    <div class="left-side">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
        <div class="img-container>
            <img/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is that it seems to not work at all when image off in another div.

I can get it working when everything is within the same div, so I'm  not sure if what I am trying is even possible.

heres a slice that explains whats happening
http://jsfiddle.net/F3UQr/

Comment: Are you asking if it is ok to put them in the same DIV or is there a reason they can not be in the same DIV?

Comment: no they couldn't be in the same div, the solution is below.Basically I was saying I could get the style to work when they were within one div but not in separate divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are missing is a position attribute on the left-side.

For the z-index property to apply, the element also need to have a position other than static.

```
.left-side {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dean_simcox/MnYa8/

Comment: Thanks, so much hair pulling was done over this XD must try to remember this now

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're trying to do.  The z-index is set for ".left-side" but the position needs to be set as well for that to take effect.  I set the position to "relative" but you can also do absolute, fixed, etc.  Updated fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/JS26k/

```
.left-side
{
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
{
```